# Passing Array in pdftools library of R

Tags: r, pdf, xls

I am trying to **convert multiple pdf files into excel version** so that through vba I can manipulate the text and find some specific figures. The code that I have written is:

```
library("pdftools")
setwd("C:/Users/mohit.bansal/Desktop/CSL")
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "*.pdf", all.files = TRUE )
filenames
txt <- pdf_text(filenames[1])
write.table(txt, file = paste(filenames[1], ".xls", sep = ""), sep = " ")
txt <- pdf_text(filenames[2])
write.table(txt, file = paste(filenames[2], ".xls", sep = ""), sep = " ")
txt <- pdf_text(filenames[3])
write.table(txt, file = paste(filenames[3], ".xls", sep = ""), sep = " ")
```

Here I pass all the pdf file names into array name filenames and then I pass the filenames one by one to convert them into excel. What I want is to be independent of the last repetitive code lines. Suppose I have 25 files in a folder I need to write those lines 25 times. I there any code line which can pass all the names at once.

Comment: just use a `for` loop

Comment: Hi I am bit new to R ...can you refer some code or question link to check how can i apply for loop. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(pdftools)

setwd("C:/Users/mohit.bansal/Desktop/CSL")

filenames <- list.files(pattern = "*.pdf", all.files = TRUE )

for (fname in filenames) {
  txt <- pdf_text(fname)
  write.table(txt, file = paste(fname, ".xls", sep = ""), sep = " ")
}
```

But, `help("for")` in the console would have provided sufficient information on how to use a `for` loop.

The "problem" with using the `*apply` family of functions for this is that there's a side-effect of dumping a result back into the environment (even though only temporarily). Even `purrrr::walk()` returns data back, but at least it does so invisibly (and returns the original data unmodified).

Comment: Thank you so much...Code worked. And surprisingly it converted 23 files in blink of an eye.

Comment: Glad it helped. R can do some of the other processing you're trying to do. It might be a good exercise to try to do some of the things you were going to do in VB in R.

Comment: Yes sure ... I will try the complete the process in R only , but at the moment I already have a working VBA code. Thanks for your help again. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(filesnames, function(i) 
   write.table(pdf_text(i), file = paste(i, ".xls", sep = ""), sep = " "))
```

Comment: No Its not working , throws an error Object filenames not found :(